# Xamarin "BindableProperty propertyChanged" does not fired when "RaisePropertyChanged"

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

I use **MvvmCross** with Xamarin Form.

Therefore, I use **RaisePropertyChanged** to notify View.
However, **RaisePropertyChanged** does not fire **propertyChanged** in **ViewA**.

I do not know where to start to debug or check local variables...

### Flow

If I change **Data.Value** somewhere, flow is like below.

1. event **Data.ValueChanged** invoked.
2. **ModelA.OnValueChanged** calls **OnPropertyChanged**
3. **ViewModelA.OnModelPropertyChanged** calls **RaisePropertyChanged**
4. expect **ViewA.OnChanged** called, but fail...

### XAML

I run and check if XAML binding is working.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ViewB">
    <ViewB Data="{Binding Data}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

### View

I defined **BindableProperty** as below.

```
// this class is abstract!
public abstract class ViewA : MvxContentView
{
        public static readonly BindableProperty DataProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(
                propertyName: "Property",
                returnType: typeof(Data),
                declaringType: typeof(ViewA),
                defaultValue: null,
                propertyChanged: OnChanged);
        static void OnChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (newValue is null) { return; }
            
            // some codes
        }
}
```

```
// actual class

public partial class ViewB : ViewA
{
        public ViewB()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
// this is also abstract!
public abstract class ViewModelA<T> : MvxViewModel<T>
{
        protected T _model;
        public Data Data
        {
            get => _model.Data;
        }

        
        public T Model
        {
            get => _Model;
            set
            {
                if (SetProperty(ref _model, value))
                {
                    // Register event handler
                    _model.PropertyChanged += OnModelPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.PropertyName)
            {
                case "DataChanged":
                    {
                        // I expect this will fire 'propertyChanged' of BindableProperty.
                        // But it is not fired...
                        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Data);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
}
```

```
// actual class
public class ViewModelB : ViewModelA<ModelA>
{
        public ViewModelB() : base()
        {

        }
}
```

### Model

```
public class LayerModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private Data _data;
        public Data Data
        {
            get
            {
                return _data;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_data != value)
                {
                    _data = value;
                    _data.ValueChanged += OnValueChanged;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DataChanged");
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(""DataChanged"");
        }
}
```

### Data

```
public class Data
{
        private int _value;
        public int Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                if(_value != value)
                {
                    // 2020.07.06 Edited
                    var evetArg = new DataChangedArgs
                    {
                        OldData = _value;
                        NewData = value;
                    };
                    _value = value;
                    ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, evetArg);
                }
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
}
```

### 2020.07.06 Added

```
public class DataChangedArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int OldData { get; set; }  
    public int NewData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to simplify some classes. You created a custom event named `ValueChanged`, its basically the same `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It's recommend you to use the interface, there are a class `MvxNotifyPropertyChanged` (in MvvmCross) that implement the previous interface.

Here is an approximation (This ViewModel does not inherit from MvxViewModel but as I said, it's an approximation).

*****EDIT** *Question update*: The class `Data` can't be modified.

You are trying to bind `Data` with a BindableProperty, in this case the `Data` should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the changes. I recommend you to read about  [`BindableObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject?view=xamarin-forms).

In this case I propose the following solution:

- Create a class inheriting from `Data`: it will implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to notify the value changes.

The structure should look similar to:

```
...
public class MainPageViewModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Data Data => _model?.Data;

    private LayerModel _model;
    public LayerModel Model
    {
        get => _model;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _model, value, () =>
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Data));
            });
        }
    }
}

public class LayerModel : MvxNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Data _data;

    public Data Data
    {
        get => _data;
        set => SetProperty(ref _data, value);
    }
}

public class Data
{
    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (_value == value)
                return;
            var eventArgs = new DataChangedEventArgs(_value, value);
            _value = value;
            ValueChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ValueChanged;
}

public class DataChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public DataChangedEventArgs(int oldData, int newData)
    {
        OldData = oldData;
        NewData = newData;
    }

    public int OldData { get; }
    public int NewData { get; }
}

public class NotificationData : Data, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static NotificationData FromData(Data data)
    {
        return new NotificationData {Value = data.Value};
    }

    public NotificationData()
    {
        ValueChanged += delegate
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        };
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
...
```

The following is an demo with an abstract view, and a child view consuming the MainPageViewModel.

The abstract view should look similar to

```
public abstract class ViewA : ContentPage
{
    public Data ModelA
    {
        get => (Data)GetValue(ModelAProperty);
        set => SetValue(ModelAProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ModelAProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: nameof(ModelA),
            returnType: typeof(Data),
            declaringType: typeof(ViewA),
            defaultValue: null,
            propertyChanged: OnChanged);
    static void OnChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        if (newValue is null) { return; }

        // some codes
    }
}
```

2. The child view.

Code behind:

```
...
public partial class MainPage : ViewA
{
    private int _counter = 10;
    private MainPageViewModel ViewModel => (MainPageViewModel) BindingContext;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //--example initialization
        var data = new Data
        {
            Value = _counter
        };
        ViewModel.Model = new LayerModel
        {
            Data = NotificationData.FromData(data)
        };
    }

    private void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Model.Data.Value = ++_counter;
    }
}
...
```

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xamstack:ViewA xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:xamstack="clr-namespace:xamstack;assembly=xamstack"
       mc:Ignorable="d"
       x:Class="xamstack.MainPage"
       ModelA="{Binding Data}">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <xamstack:MainPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <Button Text="Increment" Clicked="Button_OnClicked"/>
        <Label>
            <Label.FormattedText>
                <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="Value: "/>
                    <Span Text="{Binding Path=ModelA.Value, Mode=OneWay, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}" 
                          TextColor="Red"
                          />
                </FormattedString>
            </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
    </StackLayout>
</xamstack:ViewA>
```

I hope it match your case.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution to use **MvxNotifyPropertyChanged** but failed. And, I'm sorry to miss the necessary explanation. The reason why I use event handler than **MvxNotifyPropertyChanged** is **Data** class is used by other projects. Those other projects are using **DataChangedArgs** properties.